Querying for multiple keys from user_properties (nested) BigQuery - GA4 data
I would like to create a new table with multiple user property keys, but for some reason im getting an error. The code that I was trying
SELECT
  event_date,
  (select value.string_value from unnest(user_properties) where key = "user_company") as user_company,
  (select value.string_value from unnest(user_properties) where key = "user_type") as user_type,
  (select value.string_value from unnest(user_properties) where key = "user_status") as user_status,   
  count (distinct user_pseudo_id) as users,
FROM
  `corp-01-0934.analytics_39978931.events_*`
GROUP BY
  event_date,
  user_company
ORDER BY
  users desc

works fine for just unnesting activity, but when I add more it brakes... how to be able to extract more than 1 property key?
I was trying to modify the query above but was not able to succeed with that
The error im getting is:
UNNEST expression references column user_properties which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:42]


Add user_type and user_status to GROUP BY?
